# Since dist-upgrade, Debian crashes after a few minutes of using terminal, but only when an external monitor is not being used

Tags: debian, gnome-terminal

Two months ago I ran a dist-upgrade on my thinkpad work laptop, upgrading from Debian 8 to Debian 9. Since then I have been experiencing issues which I do not know how to troubleshoot, which only occur when a second monitor is attached.

Since then, after a few minutes of using the terminal (`gnome-terminal`, `mate-terminal`, and `x-emulator-terminal` all have this problem) my laptop screen become a pure black, with occasional flickering pixels to the left hand side. After a few seconds the laptop turns off. It looks very much like hardware fault (bad screen cable, or something).

However if it was a hardware fault I do not understand why I can browse the internet and run other applications indefinitely without computer crashes, nor why having an external monitor would magic away the problem.

I have tried looking through my `/var/log/syslog` but I cannot see any messages which appear when the crash occurs, nor any error messages that only appear when a second monitor is not attached. I do often get the message:

> `Allocating size to GtkScrollbar 0x55a1328f6290 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?`

I do not know if this related in anyway to this problem.

I cannot find anything on *"the internet"* with any issues even a little bit similar to this. 
Frankly I do not know where to begin troubleshoot this issue.